# como pasar parametro en el route desde un controller en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quiero mandar un parametro en mi route desde mi controlador

controller :

```
public function  guardarArticulo(Request $request){

        $detalle_modelo = new DetalleModelo();
        $detalle_modelo->idAutos = $request->idAutos;
        $detalle_modelo->titulo = $request->titulo;
        $detalle_modelo->descripcion  = $request->descripcion;
        $detalle_modelo->save();

        $detalle_modelos = DetalleModelo::where('idAutos','=',$detalle_modelo->idAutos)->get();

        return redirect()->route('auto.ver')->with(compact('detalle_modelos'));
    }
```

intente esto pero no sale

route('auto.ver'/{$detalle_modelo->idAutos})

quiero pasarle un parametro por que mi route (auto.ver) recibe un parametro por get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta seria una manera de pasar el parámetro a la ruta, puedes checar la documentación oficial -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects

```
public function  guardarArticulo(Request $request){

    $detalle_modelo = new DetalleModelo();
    $detalle_modelo->idAutos = $request->idAutos;
    $detalle_modelo->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $detalle_modelo->descripcion  = $request->descripcion;
    $detalle_modelo->save();

    $detalle_modelos = DetalleModelo::where('idAutos','=',$detalle_modelo->idAutos)->get();

    return redirect()->route('auto.ver', [$detalle_modelos->idAutos]);
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo!!

Comment: de nada, éxito!!

Answer (score -1):

Cambia la última linea:

```
return redirect()->route('auto.ver')->with(compact('detalle_modelos'));
```

Por:

```
return redirect()->route('auto.ver',compact('detalle_modelos'));
```

Comment: Esto funcionaria si se requeriría pasar variables pero la pregunta es pasar parametros